# Android SearchView get focus by tapping anywhere in the view

Tags: android

I have the following SearchView:

```
<android.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_user_searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:queryHint="Search here"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@drawable/search_bg"/>
```

The cursor appears only when i hit on the magnifying glass icon, how can i make it appear when tapping anywhere in the view?